# Multer doesnt populate req.file no matter what I do

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, multer

I have literally tried every possible solution to the problem but none of them works, the interesting thing is that I can indeed access req.body but cannot access req.file. If somebody has any idea please share it, thanks.

the form:

```
<form action="/books" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="cover">Cover</label>
    <input type="file" id="cover" name="cover">
    <button type="submit">Create</button>
</form>
```

routehandler:

```
const imageMimeTypes = ['image/jpeg','image/jpg','image/png', 'image/gif']
const upload = multer({
    dest: uploadPath,
    fileFilter(req, file, callback){
        if(imageMimeTypes.includes(file.mimetype)){
            return callback(null, true)
        }
        callback(new Error('the mimetype of the image is not valid'), null)
    }
})
router.post('/', upload.single('cover'), async (req, res) => {
    const book = new Book({
        title: req.body.title,
        author: req.body.author,
        publishDate: new Date(req.body.publishDate),
        pageCount: req.body.pageCount,
        description: req.body.description,
        coverImageName: req.file.filename
    })
    try {
      await book.save();
      res.redirect('/books')
    } catch (error) {
      renderNewPage(res, book, true)
  }
})
```

Comment: Are you able to access `file` in the filefilter method? Also, are there any errors which you see in the console?

Comment: Where is your `/books` route?